# is there a clear overview-diagram of the tree of algebraic structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, recreational-mathematics, education

I am looking for a nice diagram-image of all the types of algebraic structures (groups, rings,...) and their axiomatic relationships.

It would be nice to have an overview of all of them in one image.

I assume there could be many different ways of organizing them (an inheritance tree, an Euler-diagram, something else??)

The same could be done for topological or other structures :)